# Can I control column order when I use function make_response_from_records in Flask-excel?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, pyexcel

I am using flask-excel to export a list of dict to excel file. This is my code.

```
return excel.make_response_from_records(
    result,
    "csv",
    file_name="export_data",
    dest_encoding="gb2312"
)
```

I successfully got an Excel file with columns sorted by 'a b c'. How can I control the order? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please supply a list of ordered dictionary instances. According to [the source](https://github.com/pyexcel/pyexcel/blob/master/pyexcel/sources/pydata.py), yield_from_records() will follow your order, as long as the first one is of an ordered dictionary.

Comment: the dict instances are some Chinese words. Finally, I add numbers like "0, 1,..."  before each keys. It works, though it is ugly.

Comment: What I meant is: from collections import OrderedDict. And then put your key-value pair in a sequence that you prefer. OrderedDict will remember your sequence, so will Flask-Excel.

Comment: Yes. OrderedDict is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

another solution if using a database you can use the "make_response_from_query_set" and specify the column_names from an array and it will keep the order.

```
report = db.session.query(tablename).filter_by(date='2020-12-25').all()
column_names = ['date', 'org', 'activation',......]
return excel.make_response_from_query_sets(tablename, column_names, file_type='csv', file_name='somefilename')
```